# Integration test on Gradle 4.0-milestone2

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

I am migrating a Java library to Gradle `4.0-milestone2` and I encountered some issues with the integration task defined below.

This task allows me to have two different source directories `src/test` and `src/integration` and have separate gradle tasks to run them, `./gradlew test` and `./gradlew integration`.

Contents of `integration.gradle`

```
sourceSets {
  integration {
    java {
      compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
      runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
      srcDir file('src/integration/java')
    }
    resources.srcDir file('src/integration/resources')
  }
}
configurations {
  integrationCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
  integrationRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}
idea {
  module {
    testSourceDirs += file('src/integration/java')
    scopes.TEST.plus += [configurations.integrationCompile]
  }
}
task integration(type: Test) {
  testClassesDir = sourceSets.integration.output.classesDir
  classpath = sourceSets.integration.runtimeClasspath
}

integration.mustRunAfter test
```

Contents of `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'idea'

apply from: './integration.gradle'

targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'

dependencies {

  api 'com.github.ihsanbal:LoggingInterceptor:2.0.0'
  api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.2.0'
  api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
  api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
  api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.2'

  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

test {
  testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}


task copyTestResources(type: Copy) {
  from sourceSets.test.resources
  into sourceSets.test.output.classesDir
}
processTestResources.dependsOn copyTestResources
```

There are two problems with this configuration.

1) `copyTestResources` task does not work as `classesDir` is deprecated and `classesDirs` is not compatible.

2) The classpaths are not including the library dependencies. 
Compilation fails full of the following errors

```
error: cannot find symbol
error: package SOMETHING does not exist
```

Any clues on how to solve this issues? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some [tips on the Gradle forum](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/migration-of-integration-test-task-to-4-0-milestone-2/22806/6), I have it working.

`build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'idea'

apply from: './integration.gradle'

targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'

dependencies {

  api 'com.github.ihsanbal:LoggingInterceptor:2.0.0'
  api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.2.0'
  api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
  api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
  api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.2'

  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
test {
  testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

`integration.gradle`

```
sourceSets {
  integration {
    java {
      compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
      runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
      srcDir file('src/integration/java')

      integration.runtimeClasspath += integration.output
    }
    resources.srcDir file('src/integration/resources')
  }
}
configurations {
  integrationImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
  integrationRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom testRuntimeOnly
}
idea {
  module {
    testSourceDirs += file('src/integration/java')
    scopes.TEST.plus += [configurations.integrationRuntimeClasspath, configurations.integrationCompileClasspath]
  }
}
task integration(type: Test) {
  testClassesDirs += sourceSets.integration.output.classesDirs
  classpath = sourceSets.integration.runtimeClasspath
}
integration.mustRunAfter test
```

Still need to figure out how to run them from inside the IDE, as it's currently not working, but at least I can have CI again.

Comment: thanks a lot for this question and answer, helped much! The only thing for me is that now if I run integration test, the unit tests are also ran. Did you experience similar thing?